# How is $\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x+1}=\frac{\tan^2x}{1+\sec^2x}$?

Tags: trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I am reading my Calculus material and they present me this:

$$
\int\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x+1}dx=\int\frac{\tan^2x}{1+\sec^2x}dx
$$

I tried around playing with trig identities but I can't reach this equality.
So, How is
$$\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x+1}=\frac{\tan^2x}{1+\sec^2x}$$? How can I manipulate the initial expression to get to the final one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Multiply the integrand by $\frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}}{\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}}$. This is valid as long as $x$ doesn't reach some angle where $\cos(x)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\cos x \ne 0$,
$$\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x+1}=\frac{\dfrac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}}{\dfrac{\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}+\dfrac1{\cos^2x}}=\dfrac{\tan^2x}{1+\sec^2x}$$

Comment: Well... it looks so easy now.... Any recommendation of any material to master these trig identity manipulations?

Comment: @msmilkshake I recommend searching google - I'm sure you'll find some examples on some websites.